# bounding supremum with Sobolev embedding theorem

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces, functional-inequalities

I consider $d \geq 2$ and the domain $ D = [0,1]^d$. I consider a function $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ that is $k$ times continuously differentiable. [$k$ can be specified as large as possible.] I am wondering if it is possible to use the Sobolev embedding theorem to bound the supremum of the function $f$ using $L^p$ norms of its derivatives. So my question is:

Are there values of $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$ and $1 \leq p <  \infty$ so that there exists a finite constant $C$, depending only on $d$, so that the following is true?
$$
\sup_{t \in D} |f(t)| \leq C \sum_{i_1,...,i_d \in \mathbb{N}; 1_1+...+i_d \leq k} \int_{D} \left| \frac{\partial^{i_1}}{\partial t_1^{i_1}}...\frac{\partial^{i_d}}{\partial t_d^{i_d}} f(t) \right|^p dt.
$$

In particular, do the values (k=1,p=d) or (k=d,p=1) work?
[I think that I have read in another question in this website that (k=1,p=d) does not work, but now I am confused.]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know Sobolev embedding theorem?

Comment: I am not sure to understand the meaning of your question. I base my post on Sobolev embedding theorem, so yes I know it, although I am not an expert. Anyway, I looked at Adam and Fournier 2003, and it seems that the answer is no for (k=1,p=d) and yes for (k=d,p=1). (Thm 4.12, part I, case A.)